# Anodizing Process as Dielectric

Tags: dielectric

I want to use anodizing process as dielectric coating
I just want to know , if I do the process by low voltage, like 48 volts , for long time , will that coating  become resistant to 1000 volts breakdown voltage? or do I need to use higher voltages for anodizing?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the chemical anodization process, you must subject the anodized part to an oxygen bake in order to seal off the porosity of the anodization. failure to do so will cause dielectric failure of the film.